# couldn't be able to set color from colors.xml file

Tags: android, xml

in order to keep all the colors in one place i copied all my colors in a `colors.xml` file,

```
<resources>

    <color name="footerColor">#FF607675</color>
    <color name="activityBackground">#FFB7D4E1</color>
    <color name="listView1">#FFB7D3E1</color>
    <color name="listView2">#FFC5DCE7</color>
    <color name="title">#AA4C4E44</color>
    <color name="subTitle">#FF013C3B</color>

</resources>
```

but when I am setting this color in my `.java` file then they are not working,

like this,

```
date.setTextColor(color.subTitle);
```

but If i am hard coding the color then it is working,

```
date.setTextColor(0xFF013C3B);
```

I have also tried providing the complete path to my Resources file like this, but this doesn't work either

```
date.setTextColor(com.news.testapp.R.color.subTitle)
```

It is not showing error or anything but it doesn't work either.
What am I doing wrong ?

**Update:**

I tried the answer solution and did this,

```
context.getResources().getColor(R.color.subTitle);
```

where `context` is the `context` of the class assigned in the constructor like this,

```
Context context;
    public myAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> fetchedData, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, fetchedData, resource, from, to);
        this.context = context;
    }
```

but now I am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` error.

**Update 2:**

here is the complete code,

```
public class SpecialAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    Context context;

    public SpecialAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> fetchedData, int resource,
            String[] from, int[] to) {

        super(context, fetchedData, resource, from, to);
        this.context = context;
    }

    private int[] colors = {
            context.getResources().getColor(R.color.subTitle),
            context.getResources().getColor(R.color.title) };


}
```

Here is some output off logcat,

```
01-20 20:54:40.164: E/AndroidRuntime(3269): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-20 20:54:40.164: E/AndroidRuntime(3269): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-20 20:54:40.164: E/AndroidRuntime(3269):     at com.news.myApp.SpecialAdapter.<init>(SpecialAdapter.java:25)
01-20 20:54:40.164: E/AndroidRuntime(3269):     at com.news.myApp.myApp$GetNews.addUpdateData(myApp.java:358)
01-20 20:54:40.164: E/AndroidRuntime(3269):     at com.news.myApp.myApp$GetNews.onPostExecute(myApp.java:331)
01-20 20:54:40.164: E/AndroidRuntime(3269):     at com.news.myApp.myApp$GetNews.onPostExecute(myApp.java:1)
```

When I am removing this line,

```
private int[] colors = {
            context.getResources().getColor(R.color.subTitle),
            context.getResources().getColor(R.color.title) };
```

then there is no `NullPointerException` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re: update 2:

```
public class SpecialAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    Context context;

    public SpecialAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> fetchedData, int resource,
            String[] from, int[] to) {

        super(context, fetchedData, resource, from, to);
        this.context = context;
    }

    private int[] colors = {
            context.getResources().getColor(R.color.subTitle),
            context.getResources().getColor(R.color.title) };
}
```

Array cannot be initialized the way you do it. when int[] colors get initialized, context is null. You pass context to constructor at runtime.

Chenge the above code to something like:

```
public class SpecialAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
        Context context;

        public SpecialAdapter(Context context,
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> fetchedData, int resource,
                String[] from, int[] to) {

            super(context, fetchedData, resource, from, to);
            this.context = context;
            colors[0] = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.subTitle);
            colors[1] = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.title);
        }

        private int[] colors = new int[2];
    }
```

Comment: thank you, but this line `public int[] colors = new int[2]` is after the constructor so how it will execute before the constructor ?

Comment: I suggest you get a book on Java basics, variables initialization and the rest

Comment: i am learning from the book Sir, can you please tell me what this phenomenon is called ? so i can look into it ?

Comment: `private int[] colors` is a private variable. `[]` means it's array. some links for you http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076614/core-java/object-initialization-in-java.html http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_02.htm

Answer (score 1):

`color.subTitle` points to nowhere and does not exists.

1. `setTextColor()` expects a `Color`
2. Use `Context.getResources()` to access a resource from `res/` folder

So use `Context.getResources().getColor(R.color.subTitle)`.

In your code that would be:

`date.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.subTitle));`

Comment: how about this > `com.news.testapp.R.color` ?it exists but not working either.
Also your code is not working because the java file is not my main class perhaps.

Comment: `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getResources() from the type Context`

Comment: I explained it all. Look at my edit, I included the code you need to use. `Context.getResource()` was for reference only...

Comment: i tried your solution but there was no context so after searching on stackoverflow i learned how to create context using constructor so i did it. but now i am getting nullpointerexception error. please see the updated question. ?

Comment: i have added the logcat output and the entire code, please have a look

Comment: private int[] colors cannot be initialized the way you do it

Comment: @bhuvesh Please read the Javadoc... Your question was about `data.setTextColor()` which I explained. Now you're trying to get a `int[]` our of resources... which I don't get...

Comment: can you please tell me what should i read in javaDoc ? any guidance will be appericiated.

Comment: See @AlexanderZhak answer for your second question